# WCF Connection Resets on the server side (RST immedately sent for SYN, connection refused)

Tags: wcf, tcp, nettcpbinding

Could anyone clarify exactly what are the functions of [`MaxPendingAccepts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.connectionorientedtransportbindingelement.maxpendingaccepts?view=netframework-4.8) and [`MaxPendingConnections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.connectionorientedtransportbindingelement.maxpendingconnections?view=netframework-4.8) on the server side? I've read the docs, and I think this could possibly be related to a problem we're experiencing.

I think the `MaxPendingAccepts` docs may have a problem?

> “This property limits the number of channels that the server can have waiting on a listener. When `MaxPendingAccepts` is too low, there will be a small interval of time in which all of the waiting channels have started servicing connections, but no new channels have begun listening. A connection can arrive during this interval and will fail because nothing is waiting for it on the server. This property can be configured by setting the `MaxPendingConnections` property to a larger number.”

Does it really mean to change `MaxPendingAccepts` by changing `MaxPendingConnections`? I'm not clear on the difference between the two properties. We aren't currently setting `MaxPendingConnections` which [appears to default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-simplification-features) to 12 * cores (8 in our case).

We're using net.tcp binding on a high-volume service. Our users have increased dramatically over the past few years and it's an NLB cluster of 4 servers, but sometimes we get bursts of traffic where (according to perfmon) calls per sec goes up to like 200+.

We are experiencing problems during this time where network traffic monitoring shows that we get a SYN and then within 0.2 ms we send back an ACK, RST closing the connection.

WCF tracing shows no errors during this time, so I didn't think it was throttling. I had formed a hypothesis that it was [SynAttackProtect](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/c53806fa-3c62-4b2b-a85a-fb1047a231bd/sync-attack-protection?forum=winserversecurity), but so far, I can't find anything positively or negatively confirming that in the netsh trace + Network Monitor.

Perfmon shows us well under our max instances, calls, and sessions.

Right now, our server config is this:

```
MaxConcurrentSessions = 1500;
MaxConcurrentInstances = 1500;
MaxConnections = 1600;
ListenBacklog = 800;
MaxPendingSessions = 300;
MaxPendingAccepts = 20;

// MaxPendingConnections = not set, as mentioned above,
// and docs seem to indicate this is 12 * cores (8).
```

My new hypothesis is that the reason we could be sending an RST in response to the SYN is because maybe there is no actual TCP listener? Would MaxPendingAccepts being less than the concurrent calls cause this behavior?

Should MaxPendingAccepts be cranked up to 300 like the pending sessions? Should MaxPendingConnections be set? Why do the docs say to set MaxPendingConnections in order to affect MaxPendingAccepts?

I am trying to validate if refusing connections could be caused by the MaxPendingAccepts being 20.

Comment: The below link shows a good understand on this topic, wish it is useful to you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/net-tcp
http://shaimaaelk.blogspot.com/2009/04/wcf-nettcp-services-and-net-tcp-port.html